# Access Denied On LocationDataSourceHERE

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using the Premium SDK downloaded using my freemium account.
When I'm trying to access LocationDataSourceHERE, I get the following error message
`java.security.AccessControlException: Access to this operation is denied. Contact your HERE representative for more information.`
I searched everywhere but I couldn't find a solution to that. Anyone around here, could you please assist me?

Comment: "Contact your HERE representative for more information" — I suggest doing that.

Comment: @TheWanderer The thing is they give support only to PRO customers it seems and they are redirecting to SO for support. It's a loop I suppose.

Comment: Well we can't do anything, especially not without code. Even then, the error message seems intentionally vague.

Comment: Yes, but thanks. Hope anyone who experienced this issue may solve it.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: I last check two days before and I was facing the same issue. So I moved to Google maps. I'll give it a try again today and will update this thread. Thanks.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport The license key was changed by here team as alberto said. Now its working. Seems to be a silly mistake but no, I believed that the license key is fixed and not gonna change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to the project details page:

https://developer.here.com/projects and click on your project

Then make sure to be using the License Key displayed there. The team fixed a problem where wrong license key was displayed momentarily for some customers.

Comment: And yes. Thanks. It looks like they have changed the license key. Since the map was working fine except the premium features I thought the key was not changed and it didn't strike my mind.